# How to change the country where the data of Google Analytics cookies are sent?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, privacy

I have a problem with google analytics cookies.
Cookie data is currently sent to the United States and it's is not compliant.

How can I change the place where this data is sent?

I have Italian sites and after doing an analysis with cookiebot, they appear to be non-compliant.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics Terms of Service have recently been updated:

> The Google Analytics Terms of Service for customers based in Europe, the Middle East and Africa (EMEA) will be amended and transferred to **Google Ireland Limited**. The changes will take effect on April 30, 2021. Please review the amended Terms of Service if your business is based in EMEA countries.

https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/terms/it/